# Unable to use custom post type taxonomy template in the plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a plugin and that creates a custom post type and `custom taxonomy` for that post type. I simple created single page template that worked fine and now trying to use `taxonomy template` and that's never working for me. While I pasted that template in my theme folder and it works like a charm, can any one tell me how to use taxonomy template in the plugin ?

Here is my post type name: `portfolio`

single page template is: `single-portfolio`

taxonomy name is: `portfolio_category`

Taxonomy template is: `taxonomy-portfolio_category`

All those files are living in plugins main folder. Can any one point out why taxonomy works in theme folder but not in plugin folder ???.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your question is answered here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51022/default-taxonomy-template-in-plugin-override-in-theme, you only need to do something in reverse...

To use a taxonomy template from your plugin directory if one exists, otherwise fall back to the template in theme directory you would do something like this:

```
function override_tax_template($template){
    // is your portfolio_category specific custom taxonomy being shown?
    $taxonomy_array = array('portfolio_category');
    foreach ($taxonomy_array as $taxonomy_single) {
        if ( is_tax($taxonomy_single) ) {
            if (file_exists(trailingslashit(BASE_PLUGIN_DIR) . 'taxonomy-'.$taxonomy_single.'.php')) {
                $template = trailingslashit(BASE_PLUGIN_DIR) . 'taxonomy-'.$taxonomy_single.'.php';
            } else {
                $template = trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory()) . 'taxonomy-'.$taxonomy_single.'.php';
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include','override_tax_template');
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I got the point and eventually my problem solved .. :)